# Finitie difference method determine matrix A

Tags: matrices, derivatives, numerical-methods

> The second derivative with central difference is:
> $$ \frac{-T_{j-1}+2T_j - T_{j+1}}{h^2}= \frac{1}{k}Q(x_j)$$
> where j = $1,2,..., N-1$
>
> A = (N-$1$) $\cdot$ (N-$1$)- matrix, T = (N-$1$) $\cdot  1 $- vector. Determine A analytically for N = $4$

For N= $4$ the matrix A should be $3\cdot3$ and from what I have understood the values in the matrix are the coefficients of T in the equation given above for j = $1,2,3$. However when doing this  A does not become a $3\cdot3$ matrix but a $3\cdot5$ matrix.

j = $1$: $$-T_0 +2T_1 -T_2$$

j = $2$: $$-T_1 +2T_2 -T_3$$

j = $3$: $$-T_2 +2T_3-T_4$$

So A = $$\begin{pmatrix}-1&2&-1&0&0\\ 0&-1&2&-1&0\\ 0&0&-1&2&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

This is not the matrix that I should get but I don't understand where I have gone wrong. Are my equations for the different values of j correct? All help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You cannot make a square second difference matrix without imposing boundary conditions. One way or another, $T_0$ and $T_4$ have to be eliminated

Comment: @Ian I am given that T$_0$ = $300$ K and T$_L$ = $400$ K, where L is given to be 2. How do I eliminate them?

Comment: I assume you mean $T(0)=300$ and $T(L)=400$; thus $T(L)$ is your $T_N$, and the information about what $L$ is only matters for determining $h$. Anyway, since your boundary condition is Dirichlet, you eliminate the boundary variables by moving them over to the other side of the equation. In the first one for instance $(-T_0 + 2 T_1 - T_2)/h^2 = b_1$ so $(2T_1-T_2)/h^2 = b_1 + T_0/h^2$.

Comment: @Ian Oh yeah sorry that was what I meant. Okay, so then I would only take the coefficients of the equations to the left, and get that the matrix A is: $\begin{pmatrix}2&1&0\\ -1&2&-1\\ 0&-1&2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: But why would $T(L) = T_N$ ?

Comment: Ultimately you are trying to solve $k \Delta T = Q$ with $T(0)=300,T(2)=400$. So you cut up $[0,2]$ into $N$ subintervals of equal size $h=2/N$, and have nodes $x_j=jh,j=0,1,\dots,N$. Then you want to have $T_j \approx T(x_j)$. So in particular $T_N \approx T(2)$, and you already know $T(2)$, so it makes sense to set $T_N=400$.

Comment: @Ian Oh okay, thank you very much!